# an integration problem

Tags: integration

The purpose is to express $E[g(x)]$ in a different form.

***The background is:***

Let $f(\cdot)$ be the density of $X$, then
$$
E[g(x)]=\int_R{g(x)f(x)dx}
$$

Introduce now another strictly positive density $h(\cdot)$.Then,
$$
E[g(x)]=\int_R{\frac{g(x)f(x)}{h(x)}}h(x)dx
$$

and
$$
E[g(x)]=E(\frac{g(Y)f(Y)}{h(Y)})=E[Z(Y)]
$$
with $Y$ a random variable with density $h(\cdot)$,and denote $Z(\cdot)=g(\cdot)f(\cdot)/h(\cdot)$.

**Now, my question is below:**
We know the function is
$$
E[g(x)]=E[max(0,1-e^{\beta X})]=E(1-e^{\beta X})_+
$$
We can rewrite $E[g(x)]$as
$$
\int_R {\frac{(1-e^{\beta x})_+}{\beta |x|}} \beta|x| \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx
$$
By the change of variable $x=\sqrt{y}$ for $x>0$ and $x=-\sqrt{y}$ for $x<0$, the integral above can be rewritten as (AND THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER)
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{\beta \sqrt{y}})_+ + (1-e^{-\beta \sqrt{y}})_+}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sqrt{y}} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}y}}{2}dy.
$$

But I cannot get the result as above integration. My result is
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{\beta \sqrt{y}})_+ + (1-e^{-\beta \sqrt{y}})_+}{\beta \sqrt{y}} \cdot \beta \sqrt{y} \cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}y}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot dy 
$$

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have replaced $dx$ directly by $dy$, but in fact since $x = \sqrt{y}$, we have 
$$dx = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy$$

Now you find the missing term.

Comment: yes!you are right!Thank you :-)